# Prove that $m^*(B) = \inf \{ m^*(A) : A \text{ open}, A\supset B\}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I would like to prove that for $B \subset \mathbb{R}$, $m^*(B) = \inf \{ m^*(A) : A \text{ open}, A\supset B\}$. $m^*$ refers to the outer measure. Could you please see if the following is correct?

For $\epsilon >0$, choose a cover of $B$ using open intervals which I will call $(J_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $m^*(B) + \epsilon \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |J_k|$ by the definition of outer measure.  Let $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$, which is an open set (union of open sets is open), and $B \subset A$. So, I have $m^*(B) + \epsilon \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |J_k| \geq m^*(A)$, the latter inequality by countable subadditivity.

By monotonicity, I have the other direction,  $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A)$.  Therefore, $m^*(B) = \inf m^*(A)$.

I think that this may have been proven in general at other parts of this site, but it would be very helpful for my learning if you could please help me understand any mistake I made.

Comment: Are $J_k$ open intervals, or arbitrary open sets?

Comment: Open intervals.  I will clarify above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is right, but you should clarify why $m^*(B) = \inf\{m^*(A) : A \text{ open, }A \supset B\}$.

Let us write $M = \inf\{m^*(A) : A \text{ open, }A \supset B\}$ for brevity.

Your second paragraph shows that given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $A \supset B$ such that
$$m^*(A) \leq m^*(B) + \epsilon$$
Therefore, $M \leq m^*(A) \leq m^*(B) + \epsilon$. This is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, so $M \leq m^*(B)$.

Conversely, **any** set $A$ (open or not) which contains $B$ satisfies $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A)$ by monotonicity of the outer measure. Therefore, certainly $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A)$ for any open set $A$ containing $B$. Consequently, $m^*(B)$ is a lower bound for the set $\{m^*(A) : A \text{ open, }A \supset B\}$, and so
$$m^*(B) \leq \inf\{m^*(A) : A \text{ open, }A \supset B\} = M$$
We conclude that $m^*(B) = M$.